# Removing external reference from named range in copied sheet

Tags: excel, named-ranges, vba

I have a bunch of workbooks created by exporting two sheets - the data sheet itself and a sheet called `Lookups` containing the named ranges for data validation dropdowns.

The big problem I'm having is that the copying process has led to those named ranges referring not to the new sheet but to the original workbook - where the `TimeUnits` range *should* be defined as `=Lookups!$D$2:$D$4`, it's actually turned into `='\\sestofp001p\users\SEANP\WWL\Other Projects\20160531 - Ops - Port data project\Data Collection\[Port Data.xlsm]Lookups'!$D$2:$D$4`.

It wouldn't be a huge problem, except that there are 26 ranges on 312 different workbooks, so I'm looking for a handy way of removing the excess bit to turn it into a reference local to that book. Any suggestions?

Comment: Search and Replace allows you to replace data in Formulae.

Comment: you can loop over the `Workbook.Names` collection

Comment: @iDevlop, that only does formulae in the actual worksheets, as far as I can tell - it doesn't seem to change the named range references. Is there anything in particular I need to look for?

Comment: I was thinking about replacing "someExternalRef!A2b5" into a2b5

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried, but it only does formulae in the actual cells - doesn't affect named range definitions. :-(

Comment: @AndrewPerry try the approach in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try it with defining a `Name` variable and create it through VBA ? 
Like in my example below:

```
Sub Add_NamedRange()

Dim TimeUnits_NamedRange            As Name

' create the named range , modify This Workbook to your new created workbook
Set TimeUnits_NamedRange = ThisWorkbook.Names.Add("TimeUnits", ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookups").Range("$D$2:$D$4"))

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, excellent - that's just the sort of thing I was hoping for! Will it overwrite/edit existing ranges, or do I need to explicitly delete them first?

Comment: it will overwrite existing Named Ranges with the same name